# Error in Ajax Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

This is  ajax function which i need to  use, While  execute  the  code it is  showing that ")" is unexpected token

```js
function ChangePassword() {
  var email = $("#txtForgotPassEmail").val();
  if (email == "") {
    alert("Please enter the Email ID.")
  } else if (!ValidateEmail(email)) {
    alert("please enter valid Email ID.")
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "email": email
      },
      url: "/MainIndex/forgotPassword",
      success: function(val) {
        if (val == "0") {
          alert("Please enter the Valid Email ID.")
          $("#txtForgotPassEmail").val("");
        } else {
          $("#ForgotPassDiv").hide();
          $("#ChangePassDiv").show();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
}
```

> Error-Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

there is syntax error on above ajax function

Comment: Are you seriously asking us to find a typo for you? Open the console and double click the error and it will show you the line of code where the error is. Better yet, use an editor with syntax highlighting and format your code properly. It will make it almost impossible to make syntax errors like this. Now that I've formatted your code for you you should be able to easily spot the mistake.

Comment: Use any editor with a feature to highlight corresponding pairs of brackets ...

Comment: u have extra `});` in second last line

Comment: Just remove last second line **});**

Comment: Thankyou - Rory , CBroe , Rahul and Abhishek  for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add two "});"... see below
 your code

```
function ChangePassword() {
  var email = $("#txtForgotPassEmail").val();
  if (email == "") {
    alert("Please enter the Email ID.")
  } else if (!ValidateEmail(email)) {
    alert("please enter valid Email ID.")
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "email": email
      },
      url: "/MainIndex/forgotPassword",
      success: function(val) {
        if (val == "0") {
          alert("Please enter the Valid Email ID.")
          $("#txtForgotPassEmail").val("");
        } else {
          $("#ForgotPassDiv").hide();
          $("#ChangePassDiv").show();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
}
```

After change

```
function ChangePassword() {
  var email = $("#txtForgotPassEmail").val();
  if (email == "") {
    alert("Please enter the Email ID.")
  } else if (!ValidateEmail(email)) {
    alert("please enter valid Email ID.")
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "email": email
      },
      url: "/MainIndex/forgotPassword",
      success: function(val) {
        if (val == "0") {
          alert("Please enter the Valid Email ID.")
          $("#txtForgotPassEmail").val("");
        } else {
          $("#ForgotPassDiv").hide();
          $("#ChangePassDiv").show();
        }
      }
    });
  }
/* you add extra }); */
}
```

[FOR MORE JQUERY SOLUTION AND EXAMPLE VISIT](http://www.jquery.ml/)

Answer (score 0):

There is single mistake.. when you close the else portion then you used braces that's why it shows syntax error

```js
function ChangePassword() {
  var email = $("#txtForgotPassEmail").val();
  if (email == "") {
    alert("Please enter the Email ID.")
  } else if (!ValidateEmail(email)) {
    alert("please enter valid Email ID.")
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "email": email
      },
      url: "/MainIndex/forgotPassword",
      success: function(val) {
        if (val == "0") {
          alert("Please enter the Valid Email ID.")
          $("#txtForgotPassEmail").val("");
        } else {
          $("#ForgotPassDiv").hide();
          $("#ChangePassDiv").show();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```